# Apache 2 vhost with java tomcat and apache php

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

OS: Ubuntu2 
 Servers: Apache2,Tomcat 7

I'm missing knowledge of apache and tomcat configuration.

Is it possible to create a vhost
**example.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com    
        # PseudoCode   
        DocumentRootJava /var/www/example/
        DocumentRootPhp /var/www/app/
</VirtualHost
```

Where **/var/www/example/** hosts a java application and **/var/www/app** 
hosts a php application?

In other words **example.com** should fire the java app and **example.com/app** should run php Code.

### **EDIT**

I think apaches mod_proxy can do the job:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/tomcat-application
  ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Redirects all domain calls to tomcat. but how can I tell mod_proxy that a call to example.com/app should go to /var/www/app/ and should not be redirected to tomcat but should be processed by apache / PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure mod_jk for the Tomcat app (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html), and also configure PHP separately (http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php).

Ideally, you would have two IP addresses and configure each application on a different virtual host.

Comment: Tomcat and php are running but how do I get them both under one domain? See the last line example.com (root) should fire java a subdirectroy /app should fire php. Is there some kind of symlink or alias I can use for this? t book